# Create variables dynamically with a For Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop

The title plus the following example are self-explanatory of what I don't achieve :-)
The idea is to replace something + counter in order to make it work.

```
      for (var counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
        var something + counter = $('element' + counter);
        (something + counter).removeAttribute('class');
      }
```

Comment: Why not use an array, or apply those changes directly?

Comment: Why do you need to create a variable in the loop at all? Can you not just do `$('element' + counter).removeAttribute('class');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an array, but much more simply:

```
  for (var counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    $('element' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    $('element' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
}
```

Unless you wanted to store it outside of the loop, in which case use an array.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array.

```
var something = [];
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    something[counter] = $('element' + counter);
    something[counter].removeAttribute('class');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just get rid of the var altogether??

```
for (var counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    $('element' + counter).removeAttribute('class');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (var counter = 1; counter <= 6; counter++) {
    window[something + counter] = $('element' + counter);
    window[something + counter].removeAttribute('class');
  }
```

after that there will be a set of fields in window object, named something1, something2 etc (if `something == "something"`, of course)